# How to prove $D \in S^* \implies S \vdash^r D $

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, first-order-logic

Let S be a set of disjuncts. D is a disjunct. I want to prove

$D \in S^* \implies S \vdash^r D$

Where $ S\vdash^r D$ means there's a sequence of disjuncts where every member is either a member of S, or it's a resolvent of two previous members of the sequence and D is the last disjunct in the sequence. 
$$
S_0 \equiv S \\
S_{n+1} \equiv Sn\cup\{D|D=R_L(D_1, D_2), D_1, D_2 \in S_n, L-literal\} \\
S^*= \bigcup\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} S_{n}
$$

My try is with induction to prove that

$\forall n  \ ( D \in S_n \implies S \vdash^r D)$

- $n=0, D \in S_0 = S$
- Let for some n the statement is true, i.e. if $ D' \in S_n$, then $S \vdash^r D'$.
- Lets consider $D' \in S_{n+1}$

  1. case I - $D' \in S_n$, and from the inductive hypothesis: $S \vdash^r D'$
  2. case II - D' is resolvent of $D_1, D_2, D=R_L(D_1, D_2), D1,D2 \in S_n\\$

And here I'm having hard time proving the second case for the disjunct D'. How can I prove that the statement is true for that case too?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first make clear exactly what claim you are trying to prove using induction.  I assume you are trying to prove the claim that:

$\forall n  \ ( D \in S_n \implies S \vdash^r D)$

Also: your definition of $S \vdash^r D$ makes no reference to $D$. I assume you need to add that $D$ is the last entry of the sequence.

Base: $n=0$

Take any $D \in S_0$.  Since $S_0=S$, that means $D \in S$. Hence the sequence of disjuncts consisting of just $D$ is such that every member of the sequence is a member of $S$, and the last entry is $D$, hence $S \vdash^r D$

OK, for the step you're doing the two cases, so that's good. And for case 2:

If $D = R_L(D_1,D_2)$ where $L$ is the literal that $D_1$ and $D_2$ get resolved on, and $D_1 \in S_n$ and $D_2 \in S_n$, then do the following:

Since $D_1 \in S_n$ and $D_2 \in S_n$, we know by the inductive hypothesis that there is some sequence of disjuncts

$$S_{D_1} = D_{1,1}, D_{1,2}, ..., D_{1,m_1}(=D_1)$$

of disjuncts where every entry $D_{1,k}$ of the sequence is a member of $S$ or is the result of resolving two earlier disjuncts $D_{1,i}$ and  $D_{1,j}$ (so $i<k$ and $j<k$) in the sequence, and that there is also some sequence of disjuncts

$$S_{D_2} = D_{2,1}, D_{2,2}, ..., D_{2,m_2}(=D_2)$$

of disjuncts where every entry of the sequence is a member of $S$ or is the result of resolving two earlier disjuncts in the sequence.

So then simply *append* these two sequences , and add $D$ to the end of that.  So the resulting sequence $S_D$ looks like:

$$S_D = D_{1,1}, D_{1,2}, ..., D_{1,m_1}=D_1, D_{2,1}, D_{2,2}, ..., D_{2,m_2}=D_2, D$$

And now you see that every entry in this sequence is either a member of $S$, or is the result of resolving two earlier disjuncts in the sequence. Hence, $S \vdash^r D$

In other words: you can see the sequences as derivations (or proofs), and you can combine two derivations simply by putting all lines in the derivations after each other.

Comment: Yes, sorry, about that. It's exactly that. I've edited my post.

Comment: @NikolaShahpazov Agh!  I was in the middle of extending my post when the edit showed up and somehow it kicked away my edit .. not your fault though!!! Anyway, let me try again ...

Comment: @NikolaShahpazov OK, I edited my Answer.  Please see the comment near the beginning that you need to add a little bit to your definition of S \vdash^r D$

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed proof and for the notes. I've edited my post.